# What is the correct range of the 787-10?

Tags: aircraft-performance, boeing-787, range, aircraft-development

There are two conflicting values for the 787-10's range; they are:

1. 6,345 NM (11,750 km) -- [boeing.com](https://www.boeing.com/commercial/787/#/technical-specs)
2. 7,000 NM (12,975 km) -- on the same website few years ago, as well as [flightglobal.com](https://www.flightglobal.com/boeing-adds-weight-and-clarifies-range-for-787-9-and-787-10/113653.article)

Note: In its early development the value was 6,345 NM (11,750 km), same as #1.

Which is correct and why do the values keep changing?

Answer (score 7):

The range of an aircraft depends on the payload. The value you typically find is the range at *typical payload*.

You can find the **payload/range diagram** in the [Boeing 787 Airplane Characteristics for Airport Planning](https://www.boeing.com/resources/boeingdotcom/commercial/airports/acaps/787.pdf) document:

[image: 787-10 payload/range diagram]

As you can see, at maximum zero fuel weight, the 787-10 range is only ~4200 NM. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_787_Dreamliner#Specifications), the typical passenger configuration for the 787-10 is 330 seats in a 2-class layout. Assuming 195 lbs per passenger ([FAA](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC120-27E.pdf) average adult passenger weight in winter) plus 50 lbs baggage per passenger, gives a typical payload of 80,850 lbs. This would result in a range of ~6000 NM. If not everyone onboard is an adult and not everyone takes the full 50 lbs for baggage, the range can be higher of course. Completely empty, the 787-10 can easily fly over 8500 NM.